# If the empty set is a subset of all sets, why isn't it a member of every subset of a power set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $s=\{1,2\}$, then we say that $P(s) = \{\{\},\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$.

But the power set is the set of all subsets, of which $\{\}$ is one of them. So why doesn't the power set also include sets such as $\{\{\},1\}$, $\{\{\},2\}$, and $\{\{\},1,2\}$?

Comment: Because being a member of and being a subset of are two different properties.  The common usage using A in S to mean A subset S is why so many modern students are having difficulty with confusing 'in' and 'subset'.  Don't use A in S for A subset S!  You will have clarity of mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty set is not a member of the set in question. In much the same way, the set is not a member of the set, so the powerset doesn't include $\{2,\{1,2\}\}$

Comment: I didn't even think of that. Thanks!

Comment: I think another way to put it would be that {{}} isn’t a subset of the set either.